# "Police have found what appear to be human remains." versus "– What's in the box? – Chocolates to die for!" Why the different agreement?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, what

In my CD-ROM version of the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*, an example sentence for the verb 'to appear' is:

"Police have found what appear to be human remains."

Gruesomeness apart, what I find shocking is the agreement of 'appear' with a 'what' that is plural, 'human remains', whereas in the sentence "– What's in the box? – Chocolates to die for!" the agreement is in the singular even though 'what' also represents a plural noun: 'chocolates'!

Why the different agreement?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right you are! And Bradd Szonye's answer is indeed entirely satisfying. I had never heard of the distinction between free relative clauses and bound relative clauses.

Comment: What my answer adds, is the contrast between 'what' as an interrogative pronoun and as a relative pronoun, much too obvious to native speakers of English, probably…

Comment: Bradd's is indeed a good answer. Not necessarily easy to find using ELU's built-in search facilities though, where **what singular plural** got me nowhere useful. But I guess there was bound to be one, and Google turned it up when I searched for **what "singular or plural"**

Comment: The question that has already been asked is (and it should be rephrased this way) "Singular or plural verb after the relative pronoun 'what'?" Mine really is "Singular or plural after 'what'?" be it a relative pronoun or an interrogative pronoun.

Comment: It seems to me introducing the "relative/interrogative pronoun" distinction needlessly complicates the issue. After all, I can just as validly ask *"What are your names?"* as I can ask *"What is your name?"* (where in both cases I'm addressing a *single* person). Correspondingly, having been answered, I could say to someone else *"I know what his names are"*, or *"I know what his name is"*. In both cases we simply impart/derive additional information from the plurality of Bradd's ***free relative clause***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OK. I agree with you. Delete my question, then. I have tried to do it myself, but couldn't.

Comment: I'm not a mod, so I have even less ability to delete your question that you do yourself (which I think you can't do because it has *answers*). But it doesn't matter - if anyone wanting to know about this issue lands *here* in future, they'll be guided to the original anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dictionary is correct.

Appear, like seem, feel and other verbs, can act like the verb "to be" grammatically. In that case, the subject and predicate nominative have to agree in number, so "what" is plural, and so the verb here must be plural.

Answer (score 1):

*There is a reason* why the agreement of the verb with 'what' is different in these two sentences:

In "Police have found what appear to be human remains.", 'what' is **not the interrogative pronoun 'what'** as in "– What's in the box? – Chocolates to die for!"

It is **the relative pronoun 'what'** meaning either 'the thing which' or 'the things which', and 'what' represents the latter in the example sentence quoted:

"Police have found *things/fragments which* appear to be human remains."

The nature of the objects found was or might have been in question, not their number; and the uncertainty that existed is carried by the verb phrase 'appear to be', not by the relative pronoun 'what'.

In the question "– What's in the box? – Chocolates to die for!", the verb is in the singular because, not having opened the box yet, you cannot know whether its contents are one object or more!

Comment: (Downvote explanation in comment to the actual question.)